# Viewing foreground process using ps

Tags: command-line, process, ps

I can see the background process using ps. But Is there a way to view the foreground process? For example,

> $nohup process1 &

then

> ps -ef | grep "process1"

would display the process "process1" in execution.
But the above command wouldn't show a foreground process executed like,

> $process2

Comment: `ps -ef` shows all foreground processes for me. Which OS are you running on?

Comment: Are you sure process2 is still running when you typing 'ps'? Maybe it's already done.

Comment: By the time you get the prompt back, the foreground process is done.

Comment: I feel this question is *misleading*; see the [answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681234/286615) for an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

You might be confused because `ps` by default shows you the processes which are on the same terminal where `ps` is invoked, e.g. processes started from the same terminal window.

Try `ps -u $LOGNAME` or if you know the terminal names `ps -t $THETTYNAME1,$THETTYNAME2`. (The terminal names normally look like "ttyN" or "pts/N").

Comment: `ps - ef` shows all processes, not just ones on "this" terminal.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - or perhaps 'insufficiently qualified'. On my macOS (which uses a `ps` with a BSD heritage), issuing the `ps` command with no options lists processes on all 6 terminals (ttysxxx). `man ps` yields: `The ps utility displays a header line, followed by lines containing information about all of your processes that have controlling terminals.`

Answer (score 1):

Weird, the ps command allows you to monitor the status of all active processes, both foreground and background.

For example, I start the following process in a first shell:

```
$ startNetworkServer 
Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Apache Derby Network Server - 10.3.2.1 - (599110) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527 at 2010-06-18 14:14:33.277 GMT
```

And in another shell:

```
$ ps aux  | grep NetworkServer | grep -v grep
pascal    5928  0.3  1.4 661492 29216 pts/0    Sl+  16:14   0:03 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/javadb/lib/derby.jar:/usr/share/javadb/lib/derbynet.jar:/usr/share/javadb/lib/derbytools.jar:/usr/share/javadb/lib/derbyclient.jar org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start
```

The process is listed as expected (and the `+` shows that it is in the foreground process group).

Answer (score 0):

##### The question:

*"Is there a way to view the foreground process?"* The question then goes on to claim that `ps -ef` does not show processes running in the foreground.

##### Answer:

***Yes***, there is a way. Also: `ps -ef` **does** show processes running in the foreground - *but it does not show the **state** of the processes*. This is explained in the documentation (`man ps`), and may be verified in a simple experiment. Consider this example:

In one terminal, run:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null
```

In another terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep ping | grep -v grep
seamus        1161   974  0 23:20 pts/1    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
```

Note that `ps -ef` does not provide **state** information in its output. However, `man ps` explains that **state** information *is available* using the `-o` argument when comined with the keyword `stat`:

```
ps -eo pid,stat,command | grep ping | grep -v grep
 1161 S+   ping 8.8.8.8
```

Which tells us:

- the process PID is `1161` via keyword `pid`
- the process **state** is `S+` via keyword `stat`
- the `command` keyword shows `ping 8.8.8.8` spawned the process

The **state** value of `S+` is *decoded* in `man ps` under the heading of `PROCESS STATE CODE`. which tells us:

> S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
> +    is in the foreground process group

##### QED

We have seen that `ps -ef` lists the process whose PID is `1161`, and that `ps -eo pid,stat,command` reveals the **state** of PID `1161` to be a **foreground** process.

---

**NOTE 1:** *keywords* for the `-o` argument are described in `man ps` under the heading `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS`. It is explained here that keyword `stat` yields the two-character process **state**, while keyword `state` yields only the one-character **state**.

**NOTE 2:** This works on my Debian-based system (reported as version `ps from procps-ng 3.3.15`), and in macOS 10.15 (which is descended from the BSD version of `ps`).